# What does it means "use 1140px bootstrap grid"?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, graphics, grid

I have a part-time job and I must code a website. I've got a graphics and graphical overview in .psd and the guy who is creating graphics told me "it is for 1140px bootstrap grid, make it in" and I don't know If I understand.. can you please help me to understand that?  It looks like this:
[LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVGnL.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)'s page:

> Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size increases.
>
> Large devices : Desktops (≥1200px)
>
> Grid behavior : Collapsed to start, horizontal above breakpoints
>
> Container width : 1170px
>
> Number of columns : 12
>
> Column width : ~97px

Practically it means that you should design it for a Desktop screen.

Comment: Thank you, but if you look at the picture in link, you can see that content is about 70% of the page width, does bootstrap have something to keep that width to all content of the page ?

Comment: You can check at the link i provided. An option is the Medium devices Desktops (≥992px), where the container width is 970px and column width ~81px.